# Divs not center aligning

Tags: css, html

I have two divs, one placed left, one placed right. In the left div I have text, in the right div I have images. When I copy and paste the HTML underneath and repeat the same line of divs, the divs are just off of center. Why is that? here is my code -

HTML -

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">

    <br><br>

    <CENTER> TEXT</CENTER></div>
    <div id="right">

    <br><br>

        <font-size: "14px;">

            IMAGE 
            IMAGE
            IMAGE
            <br><br>

        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#left {
    float:left;width:48%;margin-right:1%;
}

#right {
    float:right;width:48%;margin-left:1%;
}
}
```

Comment: What's with the random `</td> </tr>` ?

Comment: Is that the exact HTML you are using?  Because there are some odd closing tags (`</td>` and `</tr>`) that shouldn't be there. In addition, the `<font>` tag is never closed. Also, while not related to your problem, the `<center>`, `<font>` and `<br>` tags should ideally be taken out and replaced with CSS.

Comment: Yes, you're right Steve. I have center-aligned the text with CSS now :)

Comment: When I center-align the text, all the images center align too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue you are reporting.  If you take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevemchey/9xES2/), you will see that everything works correctly.

This assumes that you are copy/pasting the wrapper `div` too.  If that's not what you want (and you only want to repeat the `div`s inside the `wrapper`), then you need to make sure that you are using `class`es instead of `id`s for `left` and `right` and that the floating gets cleared for every new row.  You can achieve this through `clear: both` on the `.left` class:

```
.left {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin-right:1%;
}
```

You can see the result in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevemchey/9xES2/2/):

Comment: OOOOOOOHHHHH. I am such an idiot. I was writing 'div id' instead of 'div class'. Thank you, Steve. That has sorted the problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the main div (wrapper), change he css like this:

```
#wrapper{
width:980px /*Could be any width*/
margin:0 auto;
}
```

This will center the main DIV wrapper.

Comment: When I change the wrapper to that, the next rows of images and text budge over to the left

Comment: Try to do away with the `margin-right:1%` and `margin-left:1%`. Leave the `float` condition. On a side note, try to use the `<p>` clause for new row of image, and always close all tags, such as `<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

The main div #wrapper you can center by doing

```
#wrapper{ 
 width: 980px; /*1024, percentage*/
 margin-left: auto; 
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

or you can align in center by making `margin:0 auto;` and removing `margin-lef: auto; 
     margin-right: auto;`

Comment: When I add that code, the other rows I have copied and pasted under my original div rows move to the left

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing the repeated div-id's and replacing them with div-class